# make a bash function for creating alias with parameter

Tags: bash

I want to make a curl function like

```
function Meteo () {curl http://wttr.in/ "$1";}
```

but doesn't work he doesn't find the city,

but I have tried with huge city like Paris .

link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld6WL.jpg .

but when I did for example curl http://wttr.in/paris its working

Comment: You have an extra space that shouldn't be there: `http://wttr.in/"$1"`, not `http://wttr.in/ "$1"`.

Comment: Also, you need a space after `{`.

Comment: And before `}`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function Meteo() {
    curl http://wttr.in/"$1"
}
```

Notice there isn't any extra space between the URL and "$1" variable.

Comment: this is working but if i make a function like this
'code'function meteo() {
    curl http://wttr.in/~"$1"
}'code'
its not working when i do meteo paris

Comment: @PaulBarbaux That works for me, but your version of `curl` might not be happy about the missing "http://" on the URL. BTW, it doesn't actually matter, but I prefer to double-quote the entire argument, as in `curl "http://wttr.in/~$1"`.